# Cloudflare and phpBB forum: users keep getting logged out

Tags: phpbb, cloudflare

Yesterday, I added the free CDN services CloudFlare offers to my forum. I used all of the recommended settings. The used bandwidth dropped drastically and the site loaded a lot faster so I was pretty happy. But then (a small) percentage of the users told me they keep getting logged out automatically.

I lowered the caching settings and a few people stopped getting logged out, but not everybody, so I disabled CloudFlare. Is this a known issue? Google didn't tell me anything useful. And is there any way I can enable it again without getting this issue?

Comment: Please include the configuration settings, screenshots are welcomed if its easier, also if you have any expires set please let us know those too. This is likely because of the expires set on the cookies.

Comment: Additionally check out: http://support.netdna.com/howto/use-cdn-with-cloudflare/ for the settings I'm referring too..

Comment: While this is old, someone will probably stumble across this. The issue here is probably that there isn't something to restore original visitor IP (needed because we're a reverse proxy). Solution for phpbb: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170746-How-do-I-restore-original-visitor-IP-with-PHPBB-

Comment: If anyone finds this through Google: if you decide to remove Cloudflare from your site and notice the number of online guests is always at 0 or 1, this is the reason. You have to revert this fix if you stop using Cloudflare.